# webpage designed for mobile platforms with reflow-like qualities

Tags: blackberry, mobile, mobile-website

I am looking for a way to use css and viewport properties to force one div of formatted text content to take up **exactly the screen width**, regardless of the user specified zoom.  Something like the reflow functionality some pdf readers have.  I'd prefer not to use javascript.

Is that even possible? I am targeting the BlackBerry browser specifically.

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell about Blackberry browser specifically, but here's a bit of general considerations:

- Don't give your page fixed width, except maybe `100%`; check on an actual device.
- Don't measure things in pixels (except raster images), use `pt`, `em` and `%` where possible.
- Be careful with floats and absolute-positioned things.

Comment: These are all good general tips, but they don't really apply to my particular problem